# A question about 'reptiles and volatiles' to describe creatures

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes

I noticed in the Wycliffe Bible, in early Genesis, that the description of 'creeping creatures' and 'flying creatures' was 'reptiles and volatiles'.

I had not heard or read of bird species being called 'volatile' before. Apparently it is from the Latin *volare*, to fly, and comes through the French *volatil*.

'Reptile', I understand, comes from Latin, *repere*, to creep or crawl, then through Late Latin, *reptilis*.

I have not been able to find a similar *-ile* ending category for fish or for land animals which do not 'creep' or 'crawl'.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, there’s “sessile” for plants. But I think the obstacle you’re hitting is the linguistic concept of “marked/unmarked”. That is “marked” things — things that have. *specific* words for them — are usually the “anomalies”, the deviation from the norm, that create *exceptions* that need to be talked about. The “unmarked” things are the opposite: the standard, the quotidian. For the audience or the Bible, farmers, herders, animal husbanders, game hunters, the four legged beasts and edible fish were the “normal” things they encountered in everyday life. They needed only words for *not* those.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The words that you are looking for are *[natatile](https://www.wordnik.com/words/natatile)* (for fish) and *gressile* (for land animals).

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) has entries for both adjectives, defined as "*Able to swim; swimming*" and "*Able to walk*" (via cross-reference to the synonym *gressible*). The OED entry for *gressile* includes the following citation that illustrates the parallel usage with *volatile* and *reptile*:

> 1659   D. Pell *Πελαγος* 193   Terrestrial. And under this term I would comprehend, 1. Gressile, 2. Volatile, 3. Reptile.

*Gressile* is mentioned also in the *[Dictionary of Early English](https://books.google.com/books?id=enmvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA315&lpg=PA315&dq=%22gressile%22),* by Joseph T. Shipley (1955):

> *gressile, gressive; gressorial;* adapted for walking. The simple forms from the Latin hardly survive in English (*cp. couth*), but we still use many compounds [...] Terrestrial creatures may be classified as walking, flying, or crawling: *gressile, volatile, or reptile.*

("gressible", p. 315)

Both adjectives are classified as "obsolete" by the OED, as is the "Birds, esp. wild-fowl." sense of the word "volatile". Regardless, if you're using *volatile* in the sense of "flying" and *reptile* in the sense of "creeping", those seem to be the usual terms used to complete this set of Latinate *-ile* adjectives for modes of animal motion. If you're not looking for these words, I don't understand the question.

Both words can be found alongside *volatile* and *reptile* in a Latin quotation from Gassendi in the book *[On Certain Modified Forms assumed by the Inductive Process in Different Sciences](https://books.google.com/books?id=YaeKPW5320UC&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22natatile%22%20%22reptile%22%20%22volatile%22&source=bl&ots=HGvkakTpre&sig=ACfU3U1Q4woptelYOas24Vzl_jRXWPRJsA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc24fDjvbjAhVKw1QKHXI2CcYQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22natatile%22%20%22reptile%22%20%22volatile%22&f=false),* by Robert Mortimer Glover (1837), p. 13.

*Natatile* is from the Latin verb *nato* "swim", and *[gressile](http://www.neulatein.de/words/start2.htm?../words/3/007699.htm)* is from the Latin verb *gradior* "walk" (the same *gress* as in the word *pro**gress***).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “But the Wycliffe Bible is still referred to reasonably frequently.” — by whom?  That's certainly not my experience (as a British Christian); in fact, I don't think I've _ever_ heard it referred to.  (I don't even hear the AV/KJV much these days, as much better translations are available these days — as this question illustrates!)

Comment: @gidds There's an organisation named for the Wycliffe Bible: _the Wycliffe Bible Translators_. This is a reference to that translation. The sense of 'refer to' I use can surely be deduced by the contrast with 'less well-known' and 'checked [number of hits on Google]'. Ask yourself (a) Had I heard of the Wycliffe Bible before reading this thread? (b) Had I heard of Glover's 'On Certain Modified Forms assumed by the Inductive Process in Different Sciences'? And I'd add (c) Would English people of Wycliffe's day have been better able to understand the NASB?

Answer (score 3):

Here, maybe [aquatile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aquatile) would work -

> **aquatile** (adjective)...  (Entry 1 of 2):
>
> [aquatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aquatic)

---

> **aquatile** (noun)
> plural -s
> (Entry 2 of 2) {obsolete}:
>
> *an aquatic animal or plant*

---

> **History and Etymology** for *aquatile*:
>
> Adjective
>
> Latin *aquatilis*, from *aqua*

(from Merriam-Webster)

---

As you have said in the question -

> I have not been able to find a similar ***-ile*** ending category for
> fish or for land animals which do not 'creep' or 'crawl'.

It takes care of the *-ile* ending category (aquat*ile*) mentioned above.